# Change Label With Tag Only

Tags: uilabel, xib

I am creating an application with multiple buttons and corresponding labels.
The layout is in a nib (.xib) file which is connected to the class I have the code below in. I'm trying to avoid using an IBOutlet for every label, since this would create a lot of extra code.

I know there is a way to reference a label using the tag:

```
UILabel *countLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:numOfTag];
```

I called this within my buttonPressed method. However, when I try to change the text

```
[countLabel setText:@"newLabel"];
```

the app crashes. Am I accessing it wrong? I'm new to XCode..Help!

Thanks :)

Comment: Is tag of label is unique??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the correct way of doing it. Firstly whenever you creating UILabel in your XIB file, you can name them there only so technically, there is no need for you to set the label values in the connected view controller. Secondly, even if you want to reset the labels at the later stage, connecting them using IBOutlets is the best bet. Scanning through all sub views and then finding a particular subview with its tag is more tedious and should be avoided in this case.

### EDIT:

For your case where you need to create more than 50 buttons and labels, I would suggest you to create a custom UIView with UIButton and UILabel in it. And then in the view where you want to display them, create objects in a for loop and display them. And when a UIButton is tapped it will be easy for you to fetch the associated UILabel though the custom UIView object.

Comment: So it would be better to have (estimating) 50 IBOutlets rather than referencing them through the tag? I'm new to this so I'll take any advice. The idea was each button was associated with a label, and the label was incremented each time it was pressed. So in that case I would probably have to create an NSDictionary to associate the buttons with the labels?

Comment: See my edited response. I would suggest you to take this approach. This should work best in your case with very less coding. Create custom UIView and recursively call it!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your label must not be found with `viewWithTag:`, so it will be nil. And when you try to access property of nil control, it might give you a crash.

Check if your label is not nil and check if it is label using

```
if(countLabel != nil && [countLabel isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    [countLabel setText:@"newLabel"];
else
    NSLog(@"countLabel is not found");
```

`viewWithTag:` will search the view in the receiver’s hierarchy whose tag property matches the value in the tag parameter. This will return first control it will encounter with tag in hierarchy. So make sure your tag needs to so unique in entire view. Just make sure you are giving immediate parent of Label instead of `self.view`.

**Edit:**

To can try this way also if you are not able to track issue.

```
for (UIView *child in self.view.subviews) {
    if([child isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] && [child tag] == numOfTag)
    {
        [child setText:@"newLabel"];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that and got this error: Testing[2903:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a77040'

Comment: Your tag matching with some other control also that is UIButton in your case. So make sure to have very unique tag, else iterate the loop over view's subviews and match your tag.

Comment: I commented out the setText and it ran, although therefore the label did not change. This leads me to believe it went through the != nil clause

Comment: Say if you are assigning tag 1 to your UILabel then no other control should have tag 1.

Comment: AH, I had a button with the same tag. It worked! Thank you all